# file_get_contents() and unicode characters in domain (like æøå)

Tags: php, unicode

Whenever I try to grab a page's content using `file_get_contents()`, and the domain has an unicode character in it, I get this:

> file_get_contents([https://møller.dk/](https://m%C3%B8ller.dk/)): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name of service not known in >FILE LOCATION<

This only happens when I have an unicode character in the domain. Here's an example:

```
file_get_contents("http://møller.dk/");
```

Comment: do you have a real example because `møller.dk` doesn't exist

Comment: @cmorrissey Sure it does. Go to http://møller.dk/

Comment: can you ping møller.dk from your host?

Comment: @MortenMoulder I did a `dig` on it and used external tools to do a dns lookup and nope doesn't exist

Comment: @Federkun No, because pinging `møller.dk` is not allowed. The problem is ANY host with æøå in the name... Does it work for you?

Comment: @cmorrissey That's probably because your `dig` doesn't support unicode characters. Try `xn--mller-vua.dk` instead.

Comment: special character domain names exist, they just need special handling. @cmorrissey How, that I couldn't say but they do exist.

Comment: I have my own domain with a unicode character in it. It works fine when I do the `xn--` part, but that does not look pretty.

Comment: whether the domain exists or not seems to be relative... it exists for me. I think it is because our regional settings allow us to use ø instead of oe, and å instead of aa and æ instead of ae. This is a hypothesis.

Comment: @Hallur Sure, but that doesn't fix my problem. Ignore the æøå and focus on unicode characters instead.

Comment: I think you may have to go through the manual on `file_get_contents()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php *"A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled. See fopen() for more details on how to specify the filename. See the Supported Protocols and Wrappers for links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have, notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they may provide."* and the Warning below that, that's if you haven't already.

Comment: @Fred-ii- This really has nothing to do with SSL though.

Comment: well, the only thing left that I can think of is (file/server) encoding.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's definitely an issue with `file_get_contents()`. cURL works fine (don't ask me to use cURL please).

Comment: *"(don't ask me to use cURL please)"* - *lol* Don't worry, I won't ;-)

Comment: @MortenMoulder thanks for posting this, I learned something today

Comment: @Fred-ii- You never know, man. People tend to ask people to do the craziest things, when all I need is is a one-liner! haha

Comment: @MortenMoulder Aye, for sure. I can honestly say that I am not one of those (although my "one-liners" are usually best kept for a stand-up comedy stage"). I learned a lot on this Q&A today, *cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Neither am I, but when documenting my REST API for the public, I would rather show 1 line that gets the job done than 10 haha. You're welcome! I learned quite a lot as well.

Comment: This is a fine addition to the Stack Q&A library. @MortenMoulder : So, I take it a "ternary operator" is out of the question *lol*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh definitely not! Ternary operators, no brackets in Javascript, and others like it are welcome! haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `idn_to_ascii()` function:

```
file_get_contents('http://' . idn_to_ascii('møller.dk'));
```

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.idn-to-ascii.php

Comment: Man that's ugly. I guess it works, though haha. Thanks!

Comment: I for one have learned something today. One never ceases to learn ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for the edit! I usually include the link just forgot this time

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Punycode](https://github.com/true/php-punycode), which encode/decode IDNA names:

```
$Punycode = new Punycode();
$baseUrl = 'ærlig.no';
$url = 'http://'.$Punycode->encode($baseUrl);

echo file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: cmorrissey's answer is awesome. This works but I don't think it's necessary. Thanks though!

Comment: Yep, the native function is the best way. Just showing some alternative.